# Conditional classNames & collection_check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, erb

In this example I am displaying all possible `Tags` on a `Post` when creating or editing a Post. I want to change the background-color to indicate if an item is checked or not, so I can remove the checkbox. You can see my failed attempt where I conditionally try to change the background-color in the class attribute of `tag_item.label`.

**How can I check if `tag_item` is checked?**

```
    <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-3">
        <%= form.collection_check_boxes :tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name do |tag_item| %>
            <%= tag_item.label class: "#{tag_item.check_box ? "bg-red-500" : "bg-gray-100"} select-none border2 border-gray-100 flex w-auto p-2 text-sm cursor-pointer text-center" %>
            <%= tag_item.check_box do |tag_item_checkbox| %>
                <p> <%= tag_item_checkbox.inspect %> </p>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

Comment: you can check `params` object like this `<%= params %>` on values it contains, and performt the values to custom css class then

Comment: this shows me only which controller endpoint I am hitting, the action and the id of the post. I just want to know if `tag_item` is checked or not. F.e `tag_item.isChecked?`

Comment: try to submit the form and check `params` again

Answer (score 1):

So, where you're doing the `tag_item.check_box ? "bg-red-500" : "bg-gray-100"`, that `tag_item.check_box` needs to really be checking whether the `tag_item` of this iteration is set on the `post` model.

You might already have a way of referring to the given post (an `@post` or `post` local), or you can refer to it in a form context with `form.object`, so then you need to check whether the current `tag_item` is in the post's tags, eg:

```
<%= tag_item.label class: "#{ post.tags.include?(tag_item) ? "bg-red-500" : "bg-gray-100" } other classes" ...etc
```

Make sense?

Comment: Thanks. Your solution makes perfect sense to me, only thing is that the condition was always false. So I had to change it to following: `<%= tag_item.label class: "#{post.tags.any? { |p| p.id == tag_item.object.id } ? "bg-red-500" : "bg-gray-100" } other classes" ...etc`

Answer (score 0):

So Im a new Rails developer but solved the problem my way, forgive me that I could not find the "rails way" to this problem. But anyways - it works like a charm.

`tag_item.check_box.inspect["checked"]` is returning if the tag is applied to the post (in edit view). The `toggle(tag_item_id)` function is therefore only for setting the `background-color` client-side as `clollection_check_boxes` and `tag_item.check_box` are handling the `checked`-status and the data when the form get submitted.

```
...

    <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-3">
        <%= form.collection_check_boxes :tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name do |tag_item| %>
            <div id="post_tag_id_<%= tag_item.object.id %>">
                <%= tag_item.label class: "#{tag_item.check_box.inspect["checked"] ? "bg-red-500" : "bg-gray-100"} select-none border2 border-gray-100 flex w-auto p-2 text-sm cursor-pointer text-center" %>
                <%= tag_item.check_box class: "hidden", onclick: "toggle(#{tag_item.object.id})" %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>

...

<script>
    function toggle(tag_item_id) {

        const label = document.querySelector("#post_tag_id_" + tag_item_id + " > label");
        const checkbox = document.getElementById("post_tag_ids_" + tag_item_id);

        if (!checkbox.checked) {
            label.classList.remove("bg-red-500");
            label.classList.add("bg-gray-100");

        } else {
            label.classList.remove("bg-gray-100");
            label.classList.add("bg-red-500");
        }
    }
</script>
```